# How to create a grouped string out of a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript

Below is a JavaScript Array

```js
[
  ["0x34","2","3"],
  ["0x35","2","3"],
  ["0x34","1","3"]
]
```

Required output:

```
<0x34>:2:3:1:3,<0x35>:2:3
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. The objective is for you to show us your attempts and we help fix them when they don't work as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are already answers here, I'll throw in one which seems to do the job.  But OP, please take to heart the comment to your post by charlietfl.  We expect to see more effort here from those posting questions.

This is how I might do this:

```js
const transform = (input) =>
  Object .values (
    input .reduce ((a, [k, ...vs]) => ({...a, [k]: `${a [k] || `<${k}>`}:${vs .join (':')}`}), {})
  ) .join (',')

const input = [["0x34", "2", "3"], ["0x35", "2", "3"], ["0x34", "1", "3"]]

console .log (transform (input))
```

We use `reduce` to do our grouping.  In that step we also append the secondary elements from our group, so that most everything is done in there.  Then we select the `values` of the resulting object, and join them with commas.

Even better would be to write or use a generic `groupBy` function as might be found in libraries such as Ramda, lodash, or Underscore, but I'll leave that to you.

### Update

A comment suggests a different style of coding:

> [A]s a friendly reminder for coding beginners: please don't code like this, unless it's only for a project that no one else works on except you. If not, stick to basic formatting guidelines, create meaningful variable names and don't be afraid to use space to make code more readable.

While I appreciate the intention, I disagree quite strongly.  Much of my recent career has involved mentoring and training junior programmers, not novices first learning to code but those in their first few years of professional programming.
One of my first goals is to get them out of their initial comfort zones by exposing them to more advanced concepts, more efficient techniques, more expressive code.  The point is to get them to *never* think of coding as rote.  If they've always done it this way, then they're not learning and growing when they do so one more time; they probably won't see the abstractions that can help lead to *much* better software.

As I mentioned originally, I would in practice build a solution for this atop a function like `groupBy`.  I'm one of the founders of [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/), and tend to think in its terms.  I would probably use some of its tools for this, something like:

```js
const transform = pipe (
  groupBy (head),
  map (map (tail)),
  map (flatten),
  toPairs,
  map (([k, vs]) => `<${k}>:${vs .join (':')}`),
  join (',')
)
```

```js
const transform = pipe (
  groupBy (head),
  map (map (tail)),
  map (flatten),
  toPairs,
  map (([k, vs]) => `<${k}>:${vs .join (':')}`),
  join (',')
)

const input = [["0x34", "2", "3"], ["0x35", "2", "3"], ["0x34", "1", "3"]]

console .log (transform (input))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {pipe, groupBy, head, map, tail, flatten, toPairs, join} = R </script>
```

I recommend to my students that they use such libraries, or, even better, build up their own versions of helpful utility functions in order to build their code on top of reusable abstractions.

As to the code presented, there is one thing I would in retrospect do differently regarding spacing.  I would choose to break that long line into several, formatting it like this:

```js
const transform = (input) =>
  Object .values (
    input .reduce ((a, [k, ...vs]) => ({
      ...a, 
      [k]: `${a [k] || `<${k}>`}:${vs .join (':')}`
    }), {})
  ) .join (',')
```

But I don't think that is at all what was meant by the comment.  It sounds as thought the commenter was suggesting something like this:

```js
const transform = (input) => {
  const grouped = input .reduce (
    (accumulator, strings) => {
      const key = strings [0]
      const values = strings .slice (1)
      if (! accumulator [key]) {
        accumulator [key] = '<' + key + '>'
      }
      const valuesString = values .join (':')
      accumulator [key] = accumulator [key] + ':' + valuesString
      return accumulator
    }, 
    {}
  )
  const records = Object .values (grouped)
  const results = records .join (',')
  
  return results
}
```

```js
const transform = (input) => {
  const grouped = input .reduce (
    (accumulator, strings) => {
      const key = strings [0]
      const values = strings .slice (1)
      if (! accumulator [key]) {
        accumulator [key] = '<' + key + '>'
      }
      const valuesString = values .join (':')
      accumulator [key] = accumulator [key] + ':' + valuesString
      return accumulator
    }, 
    {}
  )
  const records = Object .values (grouped)
  const results = records .join (',')

  return results
}

const input = [["0x34", "2", "3"], ["0x35", "2", "3"], ["0x34", "1", "3"]]

console .log (transform (input))
```

or something similar using a `for`/`forEach` loop in place of `reduce`.  (If this is not what was suggested, @MauriceNino, I apologize, and would like to hear more of what your meant.)  If this what was suggested, then I do disagree.

This does a better job of explaining in detail *how* to calculate the value, but it's very easy to get lost in the process and forget *what* it is we want to achieve here.  I don't want to spend the time trying to think like the computer.  I would much rather have the computer try to think like me.

Take for instance the variable named `grouped`.  Perhaps if we understood the business context better, we could come up with a better name than that, but as it stands, it was the best I can do.  What do we gain by knowing and having to keep in our minds the variable `grouped`.  It's defined in one statement, used in the next to calculate another temporary variable, `record` (again I don't have *useful* names to give these things), and then ignored after that?  And the same with `record` and `results`.  All this is information crowding my head when I'm trying to understand this function.

And it gets worse with the relationship with `strings`, `key` and `value`.  By learning a slight bit of syntax, we can replace

```js
   (accumulator, strings) => {
      const key = strings [0]
      const values = strings .slice (1)
```

with

```js
   (accumulator, [key, ...values]) => {
```

and not have to try to keep `strings` in our head.  This does reduce line-count, but much more importantly, it keeps the usage of the variables very close to their definitions.

When I write this:

```js
    input .reduce ((a, [k, ...vs]) => ({
      ...a, 
      [k]: `${a [k] || `<${k}>`}:${vs .join (':')}`
    }), {})
```

I choose the shorter variable names `a`, `k`, and `vs` over the longer ones because, while they are evocative of `accumulator`, `keys`, and `values`, they don't force the same sort of assumptions that those longer words do.  They have a much greater chance of being applicable to other situations where I might write similar code.  Moreover, they are right there in view; I know what they are when I encounter them because their definitions are only one or two lines up from their uses.  For some related points, see John DeGoes' excellent [Descriptive Variable Names: A Code Smell](https://degoes.net/articles/insufficiently-polymorphic).

There's a possibility that the reaction was to something here that is more problematic. Rich Snapp posted a great description of something he calls [The reduce ({...spread}) anti-pattern](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern).  This is a legitimate concern.  My version is less performant than it could be because instead of mutating the accumulator the `reduce` callback returns a new object every time.  This is an intentional choice, and I could have avoided it and still stuck with my expression-focused style by using a mutation and a comma operator, but I find that avoiding mutation is extremely useful.  If this is found to be a hot-spot in my code-base, then I will change.  But I will stick with the simpler approach first.

And I do find my approach simpler.  This is not to say that it's more familiar.  I use "simple" here in the sense made famous in Rich Hickey's classic talk [Simple Made Easy](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy/) of having fewer ideas woven together.  That's what I try to stress with my students.  Familiarity does not make your code better.  Simplicity does.  And I would argue that the version I first presented (or it's spread-out alternative) is significantly simpler than this version.

Comment: Could we find a solution with less number of code lines? I don't think so :) Very elegant solution

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito: I like coding with expressions instead of statements as much as possible.  This is less efficient than it might be, but I wouldn't bother about it unless it were a hot spot in my code.

Comment: I do like the way this solution came together, but just as a friendly reminder for coding beginners: please don't code like this, unless it's only for a project that no one else works on except you. If not, stick to basic formatting guidelines, create meaningful variable names and don't be afraid to use space to make code more readable. This is nothing against you or your code @ScottSauyet, it's just your personal preference I guess - just wanted to get that out there :)

Comment: @MauriceNino: I added a long response as an update to the question.

Comment: Wow, didn't think you would go that much into detail, and I am more than happy to discuss this, but the character count for this is not a lot, so I am trying to keep it short: I like your solution - its really creative. What I have a problem with is, that you need to take a good look to understand what is going on. The main problems I have with your style (in a professional team setting) is the unusual space between function name and parenthesis and before the dot. For the variable names, I agree that you don't have to write them out fully but one letter can be quite confusing in a single line

Comment: where a lot is going on. I would have chosen the names `acc`, `key` and `vals`, but that is no written rule either. Just pick something that the other people in your team understand. There is no point in writing code that only you can understand (other than keeping your position) and **will** result in the "legacy code" that everyone is talking about. If this code was written in my team, it would have failed the code review - keeping aside the fact that we don't write JavaScript. I do agree that at this small code snippet it doesn't make too much of a difference, but imagine a whole backend

Comment: beeing written exactly like this. If your team does not write code the exact same way, it will result in extra hours of work and I am pretty firm on that. All in all for your teaching I would **especially** not force them on your style. My days in school are not that far back (around 2 years) and I can still remember to have a hard time to grasp some concepts when the code was not written in a format that is at least close to some standard. It wasn't that big of a problem for me personally, but some others had a really hard time there.

Comment: Also, if it wasn't clear in my original comment: Your solution to the original question is completely fine in my view. There might be better solutions, there might be worse. But it is working and it's an interesting one. It's just the formatting and names that I have a problem with especially for newer programmers trying to learn.

Comment: @MauriceNino: I don't disagree very much.  The unusual spacing is something I've been experimenting with for a year or so; I still haven't decided whether I like it. I never try to force students to code to a particular style, for my teams we use commit hooks to adapt individual styles to the team standard. The only real standard we enforce is the set of allowable abbreviations.  But those are ignored if the declaration and final usage are no more than three lines apart; often then we use single-letter names.  I would also be quite happy with your solution, not so with the other answers.

Comment: May I ask why you are trying this style? Do you see any benefits in it? Everything else I agree with and it sounds like a good rule to me. @ScottSauyet

Comment: @MauriceNino: Simply because I think it's easier to read, the same reason that many people choose more space in object/array literals. Some write `{foo:1,bar:2}`.  I prefer `{foo: 1, bar: 2}`. Others prefer `{ foo: 1, bar: 2 }`. I've even found some who go as far as `{ foo : 1, bar : 2 }`. It's a matter of finding the right balance of compactness and space to breathe.  "`arr .map (fn)`" adds some focus on `map` as a property of `arr` and on the application of `(fn)` to it than does "`arr.map(fn)`".  It's certainly a subtle difference, but I (mostly) prefer it. Besides, I like experimenting!

Answer (score 1):

First you could reduce it to accumulate all arrays with the same key and then join the resulting objects values like so:

```js
const input = [["0x34","2","3"], ["0x35","2","3"], ["0x34","1","3"]];

const result = Object.entries(
  input.reduce((acc, arr) => { // Add up the arrays of the same key
    const key = arr[0],
      values = arr.slice(1);
      
    if(acc[key] == null)
      acc[key] = values;
    else
      acc[key] = [...acc[key], ...values];

    return acc;
  }, {})
)
.map(([key, values]) => [`<${key}>`, ...values].join(':')); // map it to an array and then join it with a :

console.log(result)
// Or as a whole string
console.log(result.join(','))
```

- `reduce()` goes over each item and lets you create an accumulated value (or object) out of them
- `Object.entries()` creates an array out of an object
- `map()` transforms an array according to the given function

So the idea in the snippet is, that you group the arrays by its first value into an object using `reduce()`, then iterate over all the resulting key/value pairs, using `Object.entries()` and in the end create your desired string with `map()`

Comment: Minor miss here: the initial keys are supposed to be wrapped in angle brackets.  An (untested) fix would just be to replace `([key, values]) => [key, ...values]` with ``([key, values]) => [`<${key}>`, ...values]``

Comment: Ah yeah, good catch - thanks! Fixed it @ScottSauyet

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, you could find distinct indexes (I mean 0x34, 0x35), then iterate in `input` values filtering the elements on index. Put the values found in array and `join` values to make the result string. Something like:

```js
let input = [
  ["0x34", "2", "3"],
  ["0x35", "2", "3"],
  ["0x34", "1", "3"],
];

let indexes = [...new Set(input.map((val) => val[0]))];
let finalResult = [];
indexes.forEach((index) => {
  let result = ["<" + index + ">"];
  input
    .filter((val) => val[0] === index)
    .forEach((el) => {
      el.forEach((val) => {
        if (val !== index) result.push(val);
      });
    });
  finalResult.push(result.join(":"));
});

console.log(finalResult.join(","));
```

Answer (score -1):

[Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array

```js
console.log(
[["0x34","2","3"],
["0x35","2","3"],
["0x34","1","3"]].map(subarray => subarray.join(':')).join(',')
);
```

Comment: Doesn't produce expected results which require a groupBy approach. You have oversimplified the issue